# Scrape data to input box in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP.

I am trying to scrape a webpage and pull the value to my input box.

Scrapping is done, and stored in array,

```
<?php
function codeAddress1() {
$html = file_get_contents("http://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=79401:006:0812");
preg_match_all('(<li.*?>.*?</li>)', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0][0]);
$one=$matches[0][0];
var_dump($one);
}
?>
```

On button click i called function :

```
<input type="submit" CssClass="button" value="Search" width="35%" onclick="codeAddress1()">
```

Now i wanted to save the variable $one to my input box, i tried several, its not working.

like

```
<input id="t49" type="text" class="textbox" value="<?php  echo @$one; ?>">
```

Any idea where i am going wrong.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: one in <b>D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Assessment\add-event.php</b> on line <b>759</b><br /> this is the error message i am getting.

Comment: have you done a var_dump on both $one and $matches so see if your getting the expected results.

Comment: i also suggest using an HTML parser for this task, `DOMDocument` in particular

Comment: Sounds like either the first script isn't run (use var_dump or echo to make sure the script is run to see output) or that the output and the initial script are in different variable scope.

Comment: Something is wrong with scraping: it's output is undefined

Comment: Why your PHP code is wrapped in `<script>` tag and not in `<?php ?>`?

Comment: @Ghost -- I looked at the html -- it consists solely of an simple unordered list so regex should work fine on this limited input.

Comment: @JamesAnderson actually no im not disputing or anything against regex approach, my comment was just a mere suggestion, if the solution worked flawlessly, then that should be okay

Comment: @ghost -- normally I would be nervous about using a regex on a web page as well, but I think his case is an exception as the html is brutally simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want but

```
<li>(.*?)<\/li>
```

This will give you

```
<b>Maakond</b> : Tartu maakond
```

in $matches[1][0] and

```
<b>Omavalitsus</b> : Tartu vald
```

in $matches[1][1] etc. etc.

Comment: Thats correct, i want to store the output to my input box, like $matches[1][0] to my <input id="t49" type="text" class="textbox">